# WPF - FatalExecutionEngineError when I apply TextDecorations.Underline to a Run

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a **System.Windows.Documents.Run** object and save it to a memory stream as shown in the below code. However when I set **TextDecorations.Underline** to it I get an ugly **FatalExecutionEngineError**. If I set any other properties such as FontStyle or FontWeight it works fine. Any insight into this would be hugely appreciated.

```
var run = new Run(inputText);

run.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var range = new TextRange(run.ContentStart, run.ContentEnd);
    range.Save(ms, DataFormats.Xaml);
}
```

Thanks in advance!